# Display footer at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, footer

The footer isn't displaying right at the bottom of the page. How can I fix this?

```css
  /* FOOTER */
  #footer {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5.5rem;        
    margin-left: -8px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    bottom: -8px;
   }
```

```html
  <footer id="footer">
                  
             </footer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the position to absolute.

```
position: absolute;
```

```css
  /* FOOTER */
  #footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5.5rem;        
    margin-left: -8px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    bottom: -8px;
   }

   .footer-text {
     padding-left: 20px;
     padding-top: 10px;
   }
```

```html
  <footer id="footer">
                  
  </footer>
```

Comment: Great it worked, thank you. @ZacharyMcGee

Comment: No problem @Rahni

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to use `position: absolute`.

`position: relative` just displays an element relative to its normal position. If you put `bottom: 10px` for example, it will move the element up by 10px. Using `bottom: 0px` on a relatively positioned element has no effect.

```css
/* FOOTER */

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5.5rem;
  margin-left: -8px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  bottom: -8px;
}

.footer-text {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">

</footer>
```